# How can I split order based on the vendor?

Tags: magento-1.7, module, orders, sales-order, order-splitting

I want to split the order based on the vendor selling the item. I have created a custom attribute `sold_by` in the the product details page. The order should be split on the  basis of the said attribute. This splitting should not affect the payment.

The order should be created in such a way that different order id(s) are created for the different items of different vendors.

Like, for example, if someone orders Product1, Product2 and Product3, where Product1 and Product2 are sold by Vendor1 and Product3 is sold by Vendor2.

Then, 2 orders with different Order Ids must be created where the Order1 will have details regarding the order of Product1 and Product2 and the Order2 will have the details regarding the order of Product3.

How can I achieve this ?